# Assume zero for subsequent dimensions when slicing an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have need to slice an array where I would like zero to be assumed for every dimension except the first.

Given an array:

```
x = numpy.zeros((3,3,3))
```

I would like the following behavior, but without needing to know the number of dimensions before hand:

```
y = a[:,0,0]
```

Essentially I am looking for something that would take the place of [Ellipsis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing), but instead of expanding to the needed number of `:` objects, it would expand into the needed number of zeros.

Is there anything built in for this?  If not, what is the best way to get the functionality that I need?

**Edit:** 

One way to do this is to use:

```
y = x.ravel(0:temp.shape[0])
```

This works fine, however in some cases (such as mine) `ravel` will need to create a copy of the array instead of a view.  Since I am working with large arrays, I want a more memory efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a indexing tuple, like this:

```
x = arange(3*3*3).reshape(3,3,3)

s = (slice(None),) + (0,)*(x.ndim-1)

print x[s]  # array([ 0,  9, 18])
print x[:,0,0] # array([ 0,  9, 18])
```

I guess you could also do:

```
x.transpose().flat[:3]
```

but I prefer the first approach, since it works for any dimension (rather than only the first), and it's obviously equally efficient to just writing `x[:,0,0]`, since it's just a different syntax.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. The `slice` object is what I was missing.  In my case I am now using `s = [0]*x.ndim; s[ii] = slice(None)`.  Which allows me to pull what I need from each dimension.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use tom10's method, but here's another:

```
for i in range(x.ndim-1):
    x = x[...,0]
```